# best setup for fast sustained streaming (sequential?) disk writes

Tags: performance, hard-drive, hardware-raid, streaming, hardware

i am setting up a high speed/high resolution scientific image acquisition system.  i need data write rates of ~1 GB/sec sustained for ~1 hour.  i don't have experience with raid, but my plan is to raid 0 the following:

- LSI MegaRAID 9280-16i4e
- 11x Western Digital Black Caviar 2 TB SATA III 7200 RPM 64 MB
- 3ware CBL-SFF8087OCF-10M SFF-8087 Serial ATA Breakout Cable
- GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UD3H LGA 1155 Intel Z77 Motherboard
- SILVERSTONE Strider Gold Evolution SST-ST1200-G 1200W v2.3 80 PLUS GOLD
- Rosewill RSV-L4411 4U case 12 hot swap bays

data is coming in over this pci frame grabber:  http://www.silicon-software.info/en/products/item/95-me4-vd4-cl-en.html -- i basically just need to be able to stream its full bandwidth to disk.

questions:

1. are any of these choices suboptimal?
2. will write speed be independent of the cpu?  (ie, how do i ensure using dma?)  is there a way for the data path to even bypass ram?
3. is there any bottleneck to look out for on the motherboard, ie the north/south bridges?  if so, how would i detect/avoid such a problem?
4. is this "sequential" writing?  is that the same as "streaming"?
5. i assume that with sustained writing like this, caches (on the controller, hdd's, cpu etc) are not relevant?
6. how do i ensure the psu is adequate for all these drives?  i understand i might have to worry something about amperage draws on the rails?  will inadequacies here show up as performance problems/random crashes or will it just clearly work/fail?
7. same question as (6), regarding cooling.
8. why the huge variance in raid controller prices?  what features distinguish expensive fancy cards from the built-in raid on most motherboards?  does my task take advantage of the 9280's strengths?
9. would there be an advantage to using an external drive enclosure?  does connecting to them impose a bottleneck?
10. what bios settings should i be careful with?  ahci, etc?
11. what fs is best?  the camera/frame-grabber drivers are all windows, so i'm stuck in win7.  i assume 64 vs 32 bit will improve bandwidth?
12. anything else to look out for?  what tuning should i expect to have to do?

thanks!